# MIPS Shift Instruction

Tags: assembly, mips, machine-instruction

In an `sll` instruction in MIPS, it can only take 5-bits. How would the shift work if the shift amount was more than 31? How do we represent that with 5-bits?

Thanks

Comment: If you're on a 32-bit CPU, 31 is the most bits you can shift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. `SLL` is only for 32-bit values, where shifting more than 31 places makes no sense. Use `DSLL/DSLL32` or `DSLLV` for 64-bit values.

Comment: Oh right - stupid question I'm sorry I got carried away with my complicated project that now I'm over-complicating everything.